# using the youtube API with an iframe and not a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

According to the youtube API, you should be able to create the iframe tag myself and still use the YT.Player object. I need to do this because my embedded video id is going to be from the server and I don't want javascript in script tags.

I am trying to get an image to show as the poster for the video.

I do have a fiddle, I just cannot seem to get the YT.Player to actually work. On image click it's supposed to trigger the autoplay and when the player ends it is supposed to go away, though I will probably just hide it again.

My Html

```
<section id="head">
    <div id="container" class="click-to-play-video inactive-state">
        <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="320" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0" style="display: none" ></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

My Javascript

```
$("#container.click-to-play-video").click(function(){
    $('#player').show();
    $('#head').css({"background-color":"black"});

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 },
        events : {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
});

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.destroy();
        $('#head').css({"background-color":"#aaa"});
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eLt4aybd/79/